# Music-sync'd Strobe effect in video

Tags: video

What's one way to get a strobe flash effect in video (you know, virtually, in software) that's synchronized to the beat of a music track?

Or for that matter, how do I synchronize ANY effect with music?

Comment: there are many tools and plugins which will identify beats and output a trigger - some are configurable to only search for beats in particular frequency ranges, others auto-tune themselves.

Comment: @DrMayhem Could you maybe name a few? Wouldn't that be sufficient as an answer?

Comment: Once I hunt down named ones -yes, but I can't do a useful search at work ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trapcode's Sound Keys will do the job:
http://www.redgiantsoftware.com/products/all/trapcode-sound-keys/

From the promotional text:

> Now it's easy to synchronize motion and sound in After Effects. With
>   Trapcode Sound Keys, your audio-intensive animations no longer require
>   extensive keyframing. Visually select parts of an audio track and
>   convert them into keyframes, syncing footage with audio using
>   amplitude or frequency ranges. Sound Keys is applied as a regular VFX
>   effect, so you can save its settings with your project, generate
>   keyframes into output parameters, and link keyframes to expressions.
>   The possibilities are huge, just like the beat.

By using the generated key frames you can hook them up to almost any effect or behavior that you want.

A basic example of using this plugin to drive a few "strobes":

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using AE...

The old fashioned way:

- Select your layer, hit 0 (on the numeric keypad) to do a ram preview
- Wait till the preview is loaded into the ram
- When the preview begins to playback, hit * (on the numeric key pad) at each beat
- As soon as you stop playback, you'll have a marker at each beat
- now you're ready to begin key framing according  to the beats

Red Giant's - Trapcode Sound Keys is probably the best plugin out there for automating it.
http://www.redgiantsoftware.com/products/all/trapcode-sound-keys/